The partial orders on the elements of a root system coming from the positive spans of the weights and the roots
Let $(\Delta,V)$ be a root system with a choice of positive roots $\Delta^+$. Denote the $\mathbb{N}_0$-span of the positive roots by $\mathcal{O}^+$, and the $\mathbb{N}_0$-span of the associated fundamental weights by $\mathcal{P}^+$. We can put two partial orders on $\Delta^+$ by defining that $\alpha \preceq \beta$ if
$$
\alpha - \beta \in \mathcal{Q}^+ ~~~~ \alpha - \beta \in \mathcal{P}^+.
$$
As far as I can see these two partial orders are different. Is there anything one can say about their similarities, differences, or relationship?

The root order on the positive roots, where $\alpha \leq \beta$ if $\beta - \alpha$ is a nonnegative linear combination of positive roots, is well-studied. See Panyushev "The poset of positive roots and its relatives" (https://doi.org/10.1007/s10801-006-6030-9). The other order you consider seems weird. A more common thing would be to consider the partial order on the set of dominant weights, where still $\mu \leq \nu$ if $\nu - \mu$ is a sum of positive roots. See Stembridge "The Partial Order of Dominant Weights" (https://doi.org/10.1006/aima.1998.1736).

@SamHopkins The other order makes some sense, because the dominant weights are precisely the non-negative integer combinations of the fundamental weights. Not sure if it is useful, though.

@AndreiSmolensky maybe I should've said more specifically, the reason root order on dominant (integral) weights is significant is because for two dominant weights $\mu, \nu$ we have $\mu \leq \nu$ if and only if the $\mu$ weight space of the irreducible representation $V^{\nu}$ is nonzero. The difference $\nu-\mu$ being a nonnegative combination of fundamental weights has no representation theoretic significance like this that I know of.

One can naturally extend both orders on the ambient space $V$ (but with not necessarily integer coefficients in the linear combinations), and then both become the orders associated to pointed convex cones, which are dual to each other. There is some literature on such orders, but with little relation to Lie theory.

If the root system is irreducible and simply-laced then the second partial order is vacuous: there is a unique dominant root (the highest one) which is also the minimal non-zero element of its connected component in the poset of dominant weights with the usual partial order, and any difference of positive roots is strictly below this in that partial order, so cannot be dominant. Things are only slightly more interesting in the non-simply-laced case (where the highest short root is also dominant), e.g. in $G_2$ we have $32>11$ and $31>10$, but no other order relations.
